# How to use ordering in rest_framework_json_api

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

My settings:

```
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'mobile_api.pagination.OptionalPageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 40`
```

My class:

from rest_framework_json_api import pagination

`class OptionalPageNumberPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):`

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    if 'page' in request.query_params:
        return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
    else:
        return queryset

def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    if hasattr(self, 'page'):
        return super().get_paginated_response(data)
    else:
        from rest_framework.response import Response
        from collections import OrderedDict

        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

How to use ordering? My model contains property Cod, and I want to sort by it.

Help. :)

Comment: Can you show your views, usually you would be setting the ordering there.

Comment: I'm fix View. Thank you.